# Continued fraction for $\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-xt}/\cosh t)\,dt$

Tags: continued-fractions

In one of the comments to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296314/integral-formulas-involving-continued-fractions) I posted on MSE, I got this wonderful continued fraction $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}}{\cosh t}\,dt = \frac{1}{x}\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{+}\frac{1^{2}}{x}\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{+}\frac{2^{2}}{x}\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{+}\frac{3^{2}}{x}\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{+\dots}\tag{1}$$ Another article [here](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0017) (search for "Conjecture 1") mentions that this is a conjecture for $x \geq 1$. I believe this formula $(1)$ should be true whenever both sides of the equation are defined.

Let me know if there is an elementary proof available for $(1)$.

**Update**: As mentioned in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296314/integral-formulas-involving-continued-fractions#comment2632725_1296314) the integral in $(1)$ can be easily shown to be equal to an infinite series as follows
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}}{\cosh t}\,dt &= 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}}{e^{t} + e^{-t}}\,dt\notag\\
&= 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{v^{x}}{1 + v^{2}}\,dv \text{ (putting }v = e^{-t})\notag\\
&= 2\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}v^{x + 2k}\,dv\notag\\
&= 2\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\int_{0}^{1}v^{x + 2k}\,dv\notag\\
&= 2\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{x + 2k + 1}\notag
\end{align}

Also it is mentioned there that there is a general result by Rogers which converts the above sum into the continued fraction on the right of $(1)$. If there are any references to this result of Rogers, it would be of great help here.

**Further Update**: It turns out that the continued fraction expansion mentioned above is [quite helpful in approximating $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1366301/72031).

Comment: You may be interested by Berndt's "Ramanujan's notebook III" ![page $163$](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pAVu3.jpg) and ![page $164$](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N3MCc.jpg). Concerning Roger's $1907$ paper you may read/download it at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/proceedingslond07socigoog#page/n94/mode/2up). Start with Berndt's page $164$ substitutions to rewrite the c.f. in the p.$163$ form (I didn't reverify all this...). Hoping this helped a little,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: I think the paper by Rogers is quite helpful here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unexpectedly unanswered for quite a lot of time ;)

Comment: @metamorphy: patience pays and I got two wonderful answers so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the "EGF of the convergents" way is the easiest here, at least for me (*here* and *again*).

The CF in $(1)$ is a particular case of the one I consider at the beginning of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3757207), but this time the things are easier, since the ODE we get is *of the first order*. Fix "arbitrary" $z\in\mathbb{C}$; then $$\cfrac{1}{z+\cfrac{1^2}{z+\cfrac{2^2}{\ddots+\cfrac{n^2}{z}}}}=\frac{P_{n+1}}{Q_{n+1}},$$ where $R_n=(P_n,Q_n)$ meets $R_0=(0,1)$, $R_1=(1,z)$, and $R_{n+1}=zR_n+n^2 R_{n-1}$ for $n>0$.

Then the series $R(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty R_n t^n/n!$ converges for $|t|<1$ and satisfies $$(1-t^2)R'(t)-(z+t)R(t)=R_1-zR_0,$$ the solution of which, under the obvious $R(0)=R_0$, is $$R(t)=\frac{R_0+(R_1-zR_0)\int_0^t(1+\tau)^{-(1+z)/2}(1-\tau)^{-(1-z)/2}\,d\tau}{(1+t)^{(1-z)/2}(1-t)^{(1+z)/2}}.$$

The *singularity analysis* of $R(t)$ as $|t|\to1^-$ (as covered in [*Analytic Combinatorics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_Combinatorics) by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick), for $\color{red}{\Re z>0}$, gives $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{(1-z)/2}R_n/n!=L/\Gamma\big((1+z)/2\big)$, where $$L=\lim_{t\to1^-}(1-t)^{(1+z)/2}R(t)=2^{(z-1)/2}\big(R_0+(R_1-zR_0)I\big),\\I=\int_0^1(1+\tau)^{-(1+z)/2}(1-\tau)^{-(1-z)/2}\,d\tau\underset{\big[\tau=\tanh t\big]}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-zt}\,dt}{\cosh t}.$$ Since $R_n=(P_n,Q_n)$ with $R_0=(0,1)$ and $R_1-zR_0=(1,0)$, we get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P_n/Q_n=I$.

A direct approach (for a more general class of continued fractions), using recurrences for the corresponding integrals, is taken in the book *The Applications Of Continued Fractions And Their Generalizations To Problems In Approximation Theory* by A. N. Khovanskii (in fact hard to read for me, but perhaps would be easier if simplified for the present case).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the nice answer by @metamorphy, one can also transform the series into the continued fraction by expressing it as an hypergeometric function
\begin{align}
 S(x)&=2\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{x + 2k + 1}\\
 &=\frac{1}{x+1}\,_2F_1\left( 1,1;\frac{x+3}{2};\frac12 \right)
\end{align}
(see below).

Then the ratio
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{S(x)}&=(x+1)\frac{1}{\,_2F_1\left( 1,1;\frac{x+3}{2};\frac12 \right)}\\
 &=(x+1)\frac{\,_2F_1\left( 0,0;\frac{x+1}{2};\frac12 \right)}{\,_2F_1\left( 1,1;\frac{x+3}{2};\frac12 \right)}\\
 &=2\frac{\mathbf F\left( 0,0;\frac{x+1}{2};\frac12 \right)}{\mathbf F\left( 1,1;\frac{x+3}{2};\frac12 \right)}
\end{align}
where the regularized HG functions are introduced.
This ratio can be expressed as a [continued fraction](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.7.E5):
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\mathbf{F}\left(a,b;c;z\right)}{\mathbf{F}\left(a+1,b+1;c+1;z\right)}={x
_{0}+\cfrac{y_{1}}{x_{1}+\cfrac{y_{2}}{x_{2}+\cfrac{y_{3}}{x_{3}+\cdots}}}}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
 x_{n}&=c+n-(a+b+2n+1)z\\
 y_{n}&=(a+n)(b+n)z(1-z)
\end{align}
Here, $a=b=0,c=\frac{x+1}{2},z=1/2$. Then
\begin{align}
 x_n&=\frac x2\\
 y_n&=\frac{n^2}{4}
\end{align}
We obtain
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{2S(x)}&={\frac x2+\cfrac{1^2/4}{x/2+\cfrac{2^2/4}{x/2+\cfrac{3^2/4}{x/2+\cdots}}}}\\
 &={\frac x2+\cfrac{1^2/2}{x+\cfrac{2^2}{x+\cfrac{3^2}{x+\cdots}}}}
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{equation}
 S(x)=\cfrac1{ x+\cfrac{1^2}{x+\cfrac{2^2}{x+\cfrac{3^2}{x+\cdots}}}}
\end{equation}
which is the desired result.

---

The hypergeometric form of the series can be obtained by denoting the general term of the series
\begin{equation}
 c_k=\frac{2(-1)^{k}}{x + 2k + 1}
\end{equation}
the successive ratio of the terms is
\begin{align}
 \frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k}&=-\frac{x+2k+1}{x+2k+3}\\
 &=\frac{(k+1)(k+\frac{x+1}{2})}{k+\frac{x+3}{2}}\frac{-1}{k+1}
\end{align}
with $c_0=\frac{2}{x+1}$, the series writes
\begin{equation}
 S(x)=\frac{2}{x+1}\,_2F_1\left( 1,\frac{x+1}{2};\frac{x+3}{2};-1 \right)
\end{equation}
Now, the [transformation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1)
\begin{equation}
 \,_2F_1(a,b;c;z)=(1-z)^{-a}\,_2F_1\left(a,c-b;c;\frac z{z-1}\right)
\end{equation}
gives the expression
\begin{equation}
 S(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}\,_2F_1\left( 1,1;\frac{x+3}{2};\frac12 \right)
\end{equation}
which is also tabulated [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0037.01).

Comment: Nice use of hypergeometric functions. +1