# If we know $\sin \alpha$ and $\cos \alpha.$ can we find the angle $\alpha$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For example 
$$\sin \alpha=\frac{8}{\sqrt{65}}, \cos \alpha=\frac{1}{\sqrt{65}}$$

Can we analytically find $\alpha$ ? The only thing I did was calculate $\tan$; it isn't helpful.

It turns out my question is if we know $\cos \alpha $ and $\sin \alpha$ is there a  formula for $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ ?  The only way of finding arcsin or arccos that i know is using a calculator

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many such $\alpha$'s. However, you can get one such $\alpha$ taking$$\alpha=\arcsin\left(\frac8{\sqrt{65}}\right)=\int_0^{\frac8{\sqrt{65}}}\frac{\operatorname dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

Comment: I can make  $\alpha$ unique by restricting the domain. But how to find value of arcsin without using calculator

Comment: You can get good approximations to compute it, like I did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2996568/446262) for $\arcsin\left(\frac12\right)$, using the Taylor series of $\arcsin$.

Comment: So we cannot find alpha ˝analytically˝ because sin and cos are transcedental functions? is that right ?  by analytically i mean an exact value

Comment: No, that is **not** right. The expression $\arcsin\left(\frac8{\sqrt{65}}\right)$ is an analytical expression that gives $\alpha$. And so is $\int_0^{\frac8{\sqrt{65}}}\frac{\operatorname dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

My calculator gives $1.4464...$

From Taylor series
$\alpha=\arccos(\dfrac 1 {\sqrt{65}})=\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac 1{\sqrt{65}}...\approx\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac18\approx1.4458.$

Comment: I am looking for an exact solutions if possible

Answer (score 0):

There is a Taylor series expansion for $\arcsin(x)$ as described here:

[Maclaurin expansion of $\arcsin x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197874/maclaurin-expansion-of-arcsin-x)

Then $\arccos(x) = {\pi \over 2} - \arcsin(x)$ in the first quadrant.