# Two similar integration about continued fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, continued-fractions

Prove that \begin{align*}
\int_0^{+\infty} \cfrac{\sin nx}{x + \cfrac{1}{x + \cfrac{2}{x + \cfrac{3}{x + \cdots}}}} \, dx &= \cfrac{\sqrt {\cfrac{\pi }{2}} }{n + \cfrac{1}{n + \cfrac{2}{n + \cfrac{3}{n + \cdots}}}}\\
\int_0^{+\infty} \cfrac{\sin \cfrac{n\pi x}{2}}{x + \cfrac{1^2}{x + \cfrac{2^2}{x + \cfrac{3^2}{x + \cdots}}}} \, dx  &= \cfrac{1}{n + \cfrac{1^2}{n + \cfrac{2^2}{n + \cfrac{3^2}{n + \cdots}}}}.\end{align*}

We can follow [this](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic614.html):

For the **first** one, we use
$$\cfrac{1}{x + \cfrac{1}{x + \cfrac{2}{x + \cdots}}} = e^{x^2/2} \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2} \, dt .$$
Then we must prove
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \sin nx \cdot e^{x^2/2} \, dx \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2 \, dt}  = \sqrt {\cfrac{\pi }{2}}  \cdot e^{n^2/2} \int_n^\infty e^{-t^2/2} \, dt .$$

For the **second** one, we use
$$\cfrac{1}{x + \cfrac{1^2}{x + \cfrac{2^2}{x + \cfrac{3^2}{x +  \cdots }}}} = 2\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \cfrac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{x + 2n - 1} = 2 \int_0^1 \cfrac{t^x}{1 + t^2} \, dt.$$

We need to show
$$\int_0^1 \cfrac{2n\pi}{(1 + x^2)(n^2 \pi ^2 + 4\ln^2 x)}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1 + x^2} \, dx .$$

But how can we continue?

Comment: Your MathJax code looks like something written by a lunatic.  { {{\int}} {(1+{{x^{{{2}}}}})} {{dx}} } where \int (1+x^2)\,dx would serve?  You've got plenty of nesting already without that, and your continued fractions could use some format improvements anyway.

Comment: {e^{{x^2}/2}}  where e^{x^2/2} would serve.....

Comment: See also [Euler's continued fraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_continued_fraction_formula) and [Gauss's continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_continued_fraction).

Comment: @MichaelHardy ... most automatic code writers seem like lunatics.  Can we tell which one wrote this?

Comment: @GEdgar : I'm not familiar with any of them.

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296314/integral-formulas-involving-continued-fractions) should be linked.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

Note
$$4\int_0^{+\infty}\cos(4t\ln x)\cdot e^{-2n\pi t} \, dt = \frac{2n\pi}{n^2\pi^2 + 4\ln^2 x}$$
then you only find
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\cos(4t\ln x)}{1+x^2} \, dx\right) e^{-2n\pi t} \, dt$$
you only let
$x=e^{-u}$, then
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\cos(4t\ln x)}{1+x^2} \, dx = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(4tu)}{2\cosh u}$$

then it is well know,and you can do it(if you can't,you can see this simaler problem:[Solve $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)} dx$ without complex integration.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275759/solve-int-limits-0-infty-frac-cosx-coshx-dx-without-complex-in?rq=1])